# Visual Studio Code Not Recognizing CSS Command

Tags: css, visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the opacity of an image using CSS. However, visual studio isn't recognizing the command leaving it ignored. The other CSS code in the file are working as expected.

Here is the CSS Code (image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGuHK.png)

```html
.footer > .logo-footer img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

In visual studio the line opacity: 0.5; the word opacity isn't highlighted like the words "width" and "height" are. The width and height lines work properly. The opacity doesn't and is ignored. Is this a problem with my code or a glitch with Visual Studio? And how do I fix it?

Comment: You are missing a semicolon (;) after height. Each css property must have a semicolon.

Comment: Hover over that red squiggly error notification on the next line - it tells you that you are missing a semi-colon.

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a semicolon after height. Please put a semicolon and see if it works.

```html
.footer > .logo-footer img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon `;` after `height: 100%`.

Change

```
.footer > .logo-footer img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

to

```
 .footer > .logo-footer img{
        width: 180px;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a semicolon it seems;

```
.footer > .logo-footer img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%; /* Missing semicolon here */
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```css
.footer .logo-footer img{
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
   <div class="logo-footer">
     <img 
       src="https://static.scientificamerican.com/sciam/cache/file/4E0744CD- 
       793A-4EF8-B550B54F7F2C4406_source.jpg?w=590&h=800&ACB6A419-81EB-4B9C- 
       B846FD8EBFB16FBE">
   </div>
</div>
```